# Postgresql select two rows with create date of a difference of 2 hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello Postgresql experts.

I have a question on postgresql dates difference selection. (not sure if I put it correctly)

I have a database structure like this

```
row_id varchar(32)

event varchar(32)

event_name varchar(32)

create_date timestamp without time zone
```

and of course, I have almost over 500,000 rows.

But I would like to search for two rows, next to each other that have two hour gap between the create_date, how do I do it using postgresql?

Comment: EXACTLY 2 hours? Or is there some leeway on this timespan?

Comment: more than 2 hours should be alright too!

Comment: If there's a row that has 1:59:59 gap with the next, should that one also be displayed? or is it strictly "2 hours or more, but not less"?

Comment: The rule is > 2hours therefore 1:59:59 should not be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(create_date) over (order by rowid) as prev_create_date
      from table t
     ) t
where prev_create_date < create_date - 2 * interval '1 hour';
```

EDIT:

If you actually want both rows, you can use `lead()` and `lag()` together:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(create_date) over (order by rowid) as prev_create_date,
             lead(create_date) over (order by rowid) as next_create_date
      from table t
     ) t
where prev_create_date < create_date - 2 * interval '1 hour' or
      next_create_date > create_date + 2 * interval '1 hour'
order by rowid;
```